# Oracle PL/SQL dbms_output to Jenkins console

Tags: oracle, jenkins, dbms-output

Using Cloudbees SDA CI to implement Jenkins, with Oracle 19 P/SQL running in many jobs. Using `dbms_output` in the Oracle script, the output does not show up in the Jenkins console at all. I'm looking for functionality that would allow me to print to the Jenkins console from P/SQL the same way I can from say Python using the `print` statement. I'm generally trying to do this currently:

```
set serveroutput on;
begin
    [...a bunch of code...]
    dbms_output.put_line('This is a dbms_output call...');
end;
/
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give an example of your code?

Comment: @pmdba yes, added my basic pattern to the post. Thanks.